# Endpoint.Builder missing for generated cloud endpoint

Tags: android, eclipse, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-plugin-eclipse

I'm attempting to follow the example tutorial at https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-addentities and I'm stuck figuring out how to get the `GameEndpoint.Builder` class to generate within Eclipse.

After following this and generating the cloud endpoints as described, I have a `GameEndpoint` class created, but there is no `GameEndpoint.Builder` class. So obviously I have this error

> GameEndpoint.Builder cannot be resolved to a type

I'm stumped at this point. How do I generate the `GameEndpoint.Builder` class within Eclipse, or what would prevent it?

**Code**

```
public class NewGameTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, Long> {
    protected Long doInBackground(Context... contexts) {

        GameEndpoint.Builder endpointBuilder = new GameEndpoint.Builder(
                AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new JacksonFactory(),
                new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                    public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) {
                    }
                });
        GameEndpoint endpoint = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(
                endpointBuilder).build();
        try {
            Game game = new Game();
            game.setStart(Calendar.getInstance());

            Game result = endpoint.insertGame(game);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return (long) 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out my issue after watching this video from [Google I/O 2013](http://youtu.be/lmv1dTnhLH4?t=37m4s) which is using Android Studio, but it was the same thing as Eclipse mostly.

My mistake in following https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-addentities was that you need to put your entity class into the *MyApp-AppEngine* project and NOT your *MyApp* project.

That was the source of confusion. In case it helps those in the future, here is a short breakdown of what I did.

- Put the *Entity* class you want to add to App Engine into your *MyApp-AppEngine* project.
- Right click your class and go to **Google** > **Generate Cloud Endpoint Client Library**
- Right click your *MyApp-AppEngine* project and go to **Google** > **Generate Cloud Enpoint Client Library**
- New references will be made in your *MyApp* project which you reference in your project for usage.

Answer (score 2):

**Note** This answer is based on Android Studio, but am sure it's pretty much the same as Eclipse.

I also had this issue but later found the cause.Turns out I was importing the `Endpoint` class I generated instead of the endpoint Api package. Let me be clear.When you add the endpoint module to your project, you get the `MyBean` and `MyEndpoint` classes in the endpoint package. If you take a look at the [guide](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloEndpoints) to connecting your client to your backend, the `EndpointsAsyncTask` class uses:

```
private static MyApi myApiService = null;
```

Note how it uses `MyApi` instead of `MyBean`  Now I was wondering where it got that from but I just have to take a look at my backend libraries:

[image]

The library marked `1` is the library first added to your project when you follow the guide previously mentioned. When I added a new class `Student` and autogenerated the cloud endpoint class, the second library was also added.

Long, boring story short; It is this library you should be importing and not the class.

```
import com.package-name.backend.studentApi.StudentApi;
```

and then using:

```
private static StudentApi myApiService = null;
...
StudentApi.Builder builder = new StudentApi.Builder(...)
```

instead of:

```
import com.package-name.backend.StudentEndpoint;
 ...
private static StudentEndpoint myApiService = null;

StudentEndpoint.Builder builder = new StudentEndpoint.Builder(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem in Android Studio. I generated my Endpoint class from my entity java bean but when creating the AsyncTask, now way to get the Builder.

Actually (if I take a Game java bean like you) the Builder is not depending on the GameEndPoint but on the generated GameApi class.

In other words, I had to add these two imports in the AsyncTask class:

import com.examplepackage.backend.gameApi.GameApi;
import com.examplepackage.backend.gameApi.model.Game;

while the Game java bean that you wrote and the generated GameEndpoint are under package com.examplepackage.backend